# find one of the member in the record for if statement

Tags: erlang

I am trying to see if the current record contains that member or not.

```
#U{name ="roger", age18}

#U{name = "roger"}= User ->
    Same = fun(X) ->
              if X|| {X, X#U.name} <- User -> true;
                true -> false
              end
           end,
```

I am getting error in my if statement.

Error: illegal guard expression
       Warning: variable 'X' is unused

Because #U can have multiple records in them such as

```
#U{name ="roger", age=24}
#U{name ="sam", age=23}
#U{name ="rog", age=21}
#U{name ="roger", age=21}
#U{name ="tigr", age=19}
```

So when I call #U{name = "roger"}= User I am only listing the record that have name = roger and storing it in User.

And I want to do is, whatever my current record for #U is if the id matches with the User then true else false.

This one compiles but does nothing.

```
if X#U.name =:= User
```

Please help me. I don't know what I am doing wrong, and how I am not using X??

Comment: Is the `#U{name = "roger"}= User ->` line of your code supposed to be in a `case` expression? It's hard to help you given that your code doesn't make sense due to missing context.

Answer (score 1):

Your code samples are pretty wild, so I'll just start from the beginning.

Records are sugar-coated tuples. That's all they are. Nothing more.

Erlang is not C, Algol, Go, Python, Perl, etc. So the idea of checking for a specific value in an `if` or a `cond` or whatever after you have already entered a function body is usually a wrong impulse. Use matching instead.

So let's start with a tagged tuple that looks like `{user, Name, Age}`. How would we match that in a function head? Let's say we want to write a function that treats everyone named "Anna Graham" specially, do something with their user record, run some function on their age, and return a tuple; people who have a different name get some different treatment:

```
do_stuff(U = {user, "Anna Graham", Age}) ->
    A = step1(U),
    B = step2(Age),
    {ok, {A, B}};
do_stuff(U) ->
    Result = other_stuff(U),
    {ok, Result}.
```

Note that we didn't bind the `Name` variable, because it was never used, we just matched the name directly; anyone named something else hit the default case.

Now let's say we want to do that special procedure, but only on people whose age is 24:

```
do_stuff(U = {user, "Anna Graham", Age = 24}) ->
    A = step1(U),
    B = step2(Age),
    {ok, {A, B}};
do_stuff(U) ->
    Result = other_stuff(U),
    {ok, Result}.
```

We did bind the `Age` value because we used it, but we could also have written that function this way:

```
do_stuff(U = {user, "Anna Graham", 24}) ->
    A = step1(U),
    B = step2(24),
    {ok, {A, B}};
do_stuff(U) ->
    Result = other_stuff(U),
    {ok, Result}.
```

But that's hiding a magic value inside the code, and is considered sloppy coding practice.

So what about these records? Here is some *exactly* equivalent code:

```
-record(user, {Name, Age}).

do_stuff(U#user{name = "Anna Graham", age = 24}) ->
    A = step1(U),
    B = step2(U#user.age),
    {ok, {A, B}};
do_stuff(U) ->
    Result = other_stuff(U),
    {ok, Result}.
```

(Note my use of the term "exactly equivalent". I meant it. The compiler actually takes your record apart at compile time and rewrites it the way I wrote the earlier version. Remember: Erlang records are *not* Python dicts or Perl hashes or any other K/V thingy in SomeLang. In this trivial case records are probably overkill and perhaps uglier because of the syntax; but in large, complex tuples they can be a very handy simplification.)

Or we could even write the function head a different way, stacking up the `=` signs and both matching on `age` and assigning it to `Age` at once:

```
do_stuff(U#user{name = "Anna Graham", age = Age = 24}) ->
    % stuff
```

But what if we need to do something to a person with this name if her age is greater than 24, and treat her a different way if her age is less than or equal to 24?

```
do_stuff(U#user{name = "Anna Graham", age = Age}) when Age =< 24 ->
    process_young(U);
do_stuff(U#user{name = "Anna Graham", age = Age}) when > 24 ->
    process_older(U);
do_stuff(U) ->
    other_stuff(U).
```

Or... maybe we want to do something with her based on her age, and this intermediate value will influence the additional processing done on her age. Ah ha! Now we actually have a really good reason to use an `if` or a `cond` expression within the function (we don't want to write the initial processing twice, do we?) :

```
do_stuff(U#user{name = "Anna Graham", age = Age})
    Preprocessed = step1(U),
    Result = if
        Age >  24 -> older_step2(Preprocessed);
        Age =< 24 -> young_step2(Preprocessed)
    end,
    {ok, Result};
do_stuff(U) ->
    other_stuff(U).
```

In most cases you want to stick with simple pattern matching in a function head. Usually this is easier to read. Sometimes, though, you have cases where a preprocessed value feeds some further processing based on some condition, but the situation doesn't call for complete disassembly into several new functions so an `if` or `cond` is really the best thing to use.